# How to show a progress bar notification in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using xamarin forms and i came across this plugin https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification in order to show notifications to user. But how can a progress bar be shown on notification area?
I cant find an example of how this is done.

This is the code i use for sending notification

```
         CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body");
```

Is there a cross platform solution as the above example? Or a correct implementation using Dependency Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is not possible with the local notification plugin. However, it should be rather trivial to extend the library to add an additional argument for the progress data shown on the progress bar.

Basically, you just need to pass two additional values from the Notification Builder by calling the [`SetProgress(int max, int progress, bool intermediate)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.app.notification.builder.setprogress?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9) method. This is best explained in Google's Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#progressbar).

The method were you should add the call to `SetProgress()` is [`ShowNow()`](https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification/blob/master/Source/Plugin.LocalNotification/Platform/Droid/NotificationServiceImpl.cs#L142) in the Android specific class */Platform/Droid/NotificationServiceImpl.cs*. Of course you also need to make changes elsewhere so that you can provide the *max* and *progress* values from the cross-platform code.

If the above solution seems too complex and you're not using the plugin extensively, perhaps you can just construct the notifications yourself in the Android project and execute that code using the dependency service.

---

**Edit:** I removed the Google Books link which doesn't seem to work for everyone. Instead, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications-walkthrough) is an article from Microsoft Docs, detailing how the local notifications can be created. The only additional thing that is missing from the guies is the SetProgress method which is required to show the progress bar.

Also, notice that you need to submit the notification again and again to show progress in the progress bar. Check the third reply (from Cheesebaron) on [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29154/progress-notifications) in the Xamarin Forums for a short explanation and bits of code on how it works.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I am not sure about the first solution because you have to modify the library, and i aimed for the second solution but i am not finding the free pages of that book ...

Comment: @rambo Looks like it's not open everywhere. I edited the answer to link to a Microsoft Docs article which unfortunately doesn't cover the SetProgress method. For that, you should look into Cheesebaron's answer in the Xamarin Forums.

Comment: Thanks very much for the guidance, I did it

Comment: No problem! @rambo

Answer (score 0):

There's a video on youtube that uses this plugin https://github.com/thudugala/Plugin.LocalNotification

here is the link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5aIh-UFP2mA&t=2s
https://github.com/DevHN504/ProgressBarPlugin/blob/main/ProgressBarPlugin/MainPage.xaml.cs

this is the code

```
private static int _progress;

private async void ShowNotification(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _progress = 0;

            var notificationRequest = new NotificationRequest
            {
                NotificationId = new Random().Next(),
                Title = "Progress Bar",
                Description = $"{_progress}%",
                Android = new Plugin.LocalNotification.AndroidOption.AndroidOptions()
                {
                    ProgressBarMax = 100,
                    ProgressBarProgress = 0,
                    IsProgressBarIndeterminate = false
                }
            };

            await LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notificationRequest);

            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
            {
                _progress += 10;

                notificationRequest.Android.ProgressBarProgress = _progress;
                notificationRequest.Description = $"{_progress}%";
                LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Show(notificationRequest);

                if (_progress == 100)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            });
        }
```